# An error comes up in console when trying to enter play mode in unity

Tags: unity, c#, 3d, console

Hay folks, i pray for everyone's wellbeing. I want to ask a question that whenever i enter playmode in unity, error message is displayed even though there is nothing in the console. This doesn't get fixed even after restarting unity. Any help would be great.[image]

Comment: Without a compiler error message to go off of, we'll need you to walk us through the steps to create a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of this problem. With that in hand, we can reproduce the problem and test potential solutions. In the meantime, troubleshooting steps you can take include deleting your Library folder to force Unity to re-import all assets and recompile all scripts (hopefully revealing or clearing the error), or removing/reinstalling packages via the package manager to see if any of them are causing the trouble.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is not exact but the similar process removed the errors.

Comment: Ah great! Want to write up the process you used as an Answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i have done is that remove all the packages that the project had and reinstalled them. Moreover i removed my scripts from the assets folder and reimported them. All these solved the issue.